# Automate post-database creation scripts or steps in an Amazon RDS postgresql

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am in infrastructure team, we have a requirement to automate the creation of an RDS postgreSQL database and post-database creation scripts. This database is for Qlik sense product that's the reason application is not handling the post-database creation scripts like creating a database, login role...etc.

I created Postgres RDS multi AZ database instance using terraform but finding difficult to choose the best option to automate the creation of post-database creation scripts. Can someone suggest which option you are following at your work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use something like the [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) provisioner to run a script after terraform creates the database.

Comment: Thanks jordanm. We will be using it in gitlab ci/cd pipeline. Do you think local-exec is the best option here?

Answer (score 0):

As @jordanm suggested, with the help of others I tried following code and it's worked. I kept all the sql queries in 'queries.sql' file. Since local-exec runs the script in local machine I needed to install psql before running the post-database scripts from 'queries.sql' file.

```
resource "null_resource" "setup_db" {
  depends_on = ["aws_db_instance.example-db"] #wait for the db to be ready
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    working_dir = "/tmp"
    command     = <<-EOT
        #!/bin/bash
        sudo yum update -y
        sudo yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
        sudo yum install postgresql -y
        export PGPASSWORD = ${aws_ssm_parameter.db-password-param.value}
        psql --host=${aws_db_instance.example-db.endpoint} --port=5432 --username=USERNAME--dbname=DBNAME < queries.sql
    EOT
    }
}
```